# How to remove duplicate pages from a PDF?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I have a pdf of an ebook which has many pages duplicated, and I would like to remove them.

Comment: @user769394 how can you remove duplicate pages using this application? I tried but didn't figure it out ):

Answer (score -1):

There are many PDF toolkits that could do this.  You don't say which language or framework, so it's hard to recommend one.

You could also use Adobe Acrobat if you don't want to do it programmatically.

Disclaimer: I work for Atalasoft

Our DotImage Document Imaging Toolkit has PDF page manipulation classes.  Tutorial here:

http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/white-papers/building-pdf-documents-with-dotimage

It shows adding pages, but we also support removing (and reordering)